# How to join an NSArray output to an NSString separated with commas

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm using the following code to try to join the array output into an NSString.

```
NSArray  *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"id"], nil];
NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"joinedString is %@", joinedString);
```

I would like this to output the joined string as: joined string is 55,56,57,66,88... etc... at the moment the output is:

```
2013-03-05 13:13:17.052  [63705:907] joinedString is 55
2013-03-05 13:13:17.056  [63705:907] joinedString is 56
2013-03-05 13:13:17.060  [63705:907] joinedString is 57
2013-03-05 13:13:17.064  [63705:907] joinedString is 66
```

Comment: joinedString = [joinedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","]];

Comment: Why not to go for a nsstring category or function

Comment: I cant believe the out put to be as you are showing, your code is correct, try clean and build again.

Comment: your code give's me this output `joinedString is 55,66,77,88,99` so they are right

Comment: @hanumanDev put `NSLog` for array1.... and show the o/p...

Comment: To get this output it would have to be in a `for loop` when you are doing all of the code you have provided this is the only way I got the output you have shown. Please provide all code.

Comment: it's not complete code

Comment: @Rajneesh071 agreed this isn't complete. I believe this code is wrapped in a `for loop`. -1 will remove if question code is completed.

Comment: -1 ?? not from my side

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably running the join method inside a loop.

I suppose this is what you want.

```
NSMutableArray * array1 = [NSMutableArray array]; // create a Mutable array

for(id item in items){
      [array1 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]]; // Add the values to this created mutable array
}

NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"joinedString is %@", joinedString);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it as,

take for example

```
NSArray *array=@[@"A",@"B",@"C"];
NSString *string=[array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Output is :

```
A,B,C
```

Answer (score 1):

What ever you are writing that one correct may be problem in `[item objectForKey:@"id"]` once check this one other all are fine.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                             initWithObjects:@"55",@"56",@"57",@"58", nil];

    NSString *joinedString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"%@",joinedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been commenting on a couple of the answers here and found that most of the answers are just giving the code provided as the answer to solve this code, and the reason for that is because the code provided (See Provided code) works perfectly fine.

(Provide by question asker)

```
NSArray  *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"id"], nil];
NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"joinedString is %@", joinedString);
```

As the user hasn't provided how the `item` `NSDictionary` is created I am assuming that an `NSArray` has been created which contains some `NSDictionaries`

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"55", @"id", nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"65", @"id", nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"75", @"id", nil],
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"65", @"id", nil],
                  nil];
```

The problem is with the code that hasn't been provide, because we know that `item` is an `NSDictionary` we know that `[item objectForKey:@"id"]` doesn't return an individual items it returns an `NSArray` of ids. So based on if it was an `NSArray` it would log something like `joinedString is (55, 56, 57...)"`. We also know that it can't just be a string as we would also only have one value than so it would log some thing like this `joinedString is 55,` and again this isn't what is wanted so. the only way to get what has been provided would be to have something like this

```
 for(NSDictionary *item in array) {

    NSArray  *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"id"], nil];
    NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"joinedString is %@", joinedString);
 }
```

So if this is the case than the way to resolve this would be to do

```
  NSMutableArray  *array1 = [NSMutableArray array];
  for(NSDictionary *item in array) {

     [array1 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];

  }
  // Note that this doesn't need to be in a for loop `componentsJoinedByString:` only needs to run once.
  NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
  NSLog(@"joinedString is %@", joinedString);
```

The output of this would be (As user wants)

```
  joinedString is 55,65,75,65
```

Once the question asker provides the missing code I will correct his to answer based on there code but until then I am assuming.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

First Check `[item objectForKey:@"id"]` it is proper or not ??

And Then use following code :

```
NSArray  *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"id"], nil];
NSString *commaSpStr;

commaSpStr = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

NSLog(@"%@", commaSpStr);
```

Comment: Should `commaSpStr = [listOfSelectedItem componentsJoinedByString:@", "]; NSLog(@"%@", commaSpStr);` this not be outside the `for loop`? The `for loop` adds the objects to the array and then you will join them objects into one string using the function `componentsJoinedByString:` you don't need to loop through it to create the string see PraveenS answer. Please note I didn't downvote as this can be easily corrected.

Comment: @Popeye-- first check my answer , i checked it, it is fine :(

Comment: @iPatel you are right, there must be some functionality ,so you cant downvote without puting reason in comment.@downvoter consider that.

Comment: @iPatel The end outcome is what the user wants but you also get `55` than `55 56` and then `55 56 57` which is not what the user wants they just want the final out `55 56 57 ...` if you move those two lines I have said below the the `for loop` you get the output `55 56 57 ...` as expected.

Comment: @Popeye - check my edit ...its work properly i checked it in my xcode :)

Comment: @iPatel Agree it does work and gives the output `55 56 57...` now. But I still don't see why you have `commaSpStr = [listOfSelectedItem componentsJoinedByString:@", "];` in the `for loop` this really only needs to run once. +1 for edit.

Comment: @Popeye- really thanks ...i dont know that i cant work  this statement with only one time also ...thanks for clear my logic :)

Comment: @iPatel no problem if I could give another +1 I would for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You are **recreating** `array1` everytime. Create an instance variable of `array1`, insert `[item objectForKey:@"id"]` value to it and you will see `joinedString` will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *item in array) {
    [arr addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];
}

NSString *joinedStr = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```